# How to open a File stream in new tab in Blazor Web Assembly?

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I have scenario, where i have a API, which will return FileStream(with Content Type `application/pdf`). On  Button click i need to call the API & get the file stream & open the stream in a New Tab.

have tried "IJsRuntime". but below code seems not working. Is there any other way to handle this?

```
jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("open", "File_Stream", "_blank")
```

*I am new to Blazor.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have tried from my side. Below approach worked for me.

In Razor page add required button or label & add the Onclick eventHandler code along with Injection with IjsRuntime.

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<button @onclick="GetFilecontent">Click Here</button>


@code {

    private async Task GetFilecontent() 
    {
        var result = await Http.GetAsync("api/getFileBytes"); //Output should be FileContent
        var FileStream = result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result.ToArray();
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("openInNewTab",FileStream);
    }
}
```

> openInNewTab is the Js function which will take the File stream & will render in a new tab with the File Array.

Create a HTML file , where the File will render.

```
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script>
        function openInNewTab(array) {
            // Create a Blob object from the array
            var file = new Blob([array], { type: 'application/pdf'});
            // Create a URL for the Blob
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            // Open the URL in a new tab
            window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
        }
    </script>
```

File will open in  new window.

Comment: Do you have an idea, how one could make the name prettier? Currently, the URL and the downloaded file are just GUIDs